# MediaWiki tag parse each time

Tags: php, mediawiki

Basically, I have a dynamic php function that get's a Minecraft Server's status (using packets etc). The main problem is that the code is parsed when edited (I can see it in the logs) and not when the page is loaded. The extension checks for the `<status />` tag and replaces it with the status (a div with contents).

The source code that matters:

```
$wgExtensionCredits['parsehook'][] = array(
  'name' => 'MCStatusTag',
  'author' => 'ZephireNZ',
  'url' => '/* Redacted */',
);
$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'registerStatusTag';

function registerStatusTag(Parser $parser) {
  $parser->setHook('status','printStatusTag');
  return true;
}

function printStatusTag($input, array $args, Parser $parser, PPFrame $frame) {

    $parser->disableCache(); // I tried disabling cache as suggested, but it doesn't work.

    // Return constructed html;

}
```

How can I get it to replace the tag each time a page with that tag is viewed? Is there a hook that will allow this? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Nobody can help me? Nobody?

Answer (score 0):

If it works as advertised, the [MagicNoCache extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MagicNoCache) will do what you need, i.e. disabling the cache on that specific page.